If $E \in \mathcal{A}$ satisfies $\mu(E)>0$, then there exists $F \subset E, F \in \mathcal{A}$ with $0 < \mu(F) < \infty$
Suppose $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure space. If $E \in \mathcal{A}$ satisfies $\mu(E)>0$, then there exists $F \subset E, F \in \mathcal{A}$ with $0 < \mu(F) < \infty$
We are given very minimal information to work with so I suspect the result must be pretty straightforward. As $E \in \mathcal{A}$, then $E$ a countable union, intersection, and/or complement of other sets in $\mathcal{A}$. Given that the measure $\mu$ preserves measures of unions of disjoint sets, perhaps it would be most intuitive to partition $E$ in the following way:
$$E= \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i \hspace{1.3cm} E_j \cap E_k = \varnothing, \hspace{0.2cm} j \neq k$$
where each $E_i \in \mathcal{A}$. The cheap argument would be to pick some $E_i$ out of this collection which has positive measure (but what if $E_i$ has measure zero?). Then instead it may be better to pick a subcollection $\{E_{i_k}\}_{k=1}^\infty$ from $\{E_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ so that $\cup_k E_{i_k}$ has positive measure $-$ but we do not know which sets to select. In particular, if $\mu(E) = \infty$, then picking the wrong $E_i$ in the collection would result in another subset with infinite measure.
Is partitioning $E$ in the manner as above the best way to  approach this or is there a better way of looking at it?
NOTICE After reading the comments and asnwers, I'm seeing that my notation is mildly confusion. My use of the symbol "$\subset$" is a mere subsethood; it makes no distinction between proper and non-proper inclusion. Hence, $A \subset B \iff \forall \, x \in A, x \in B$

The fact that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite tells us that we can write $E$ as a countable union of disjoint measurable sets that have finite measure. It cannot be that they all have measure zero because that would contradict that $\mu(E)>0$.

Version 1: $F\subset E$ means $F\subsetneq E$:
This is in general false. We can have "atoms". For example, let $X$ be any nonempty set, $x_0\in X$, $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{P}(X)$ (power set of $X$) and $\mu=\delta_{x_0}$ (Dirac delta measure at $x_0$). Now let $F=\{x_0\}$. By definition we have $\mu(F)=1$. However, the only proper subset of $\{x_0\}$ is the empty set, which has zero measure.
Measure which have the slightly stronger property $0<\mu(F)<\mu(E)$ are called non-atomic measures.
Version 2: $F\subset E$ means $F\subseteq E$
In this case we are golden. As $\mu$ is sigma-finite, we can find a partition $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of $X$ all having finite measure. This means
$$ X= \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} X_n, $$
$X_j \cap X_k = \emptyset$ for $j\neq k$ and $\mu(X_m)<\infty$.
With this we define $E_n=E\cap X_n$ and note that $(E_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ forms a partition of $E$, hence,
$$ 0<\mu(E)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \mu(E_n). $$
As $\mu(E_n)\geq 0$ this means that there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\mu(E_N)>0$. Furthermore, we have $E_N=E\cap X_N \subseteq X_N$ and hence
$$ \mu(E_N) \leq \mu(X_N) <\infty. $$
Thus, $F=E_N$ satisfies all the properties you are looking for as $E_N = E\cap X_N \subseteq E$.

I think that in the question $E=F$ is allowed.

@drhab I see, in that case we are in good shape :)

With the definition I know of "atomic measure" (eg this), I think there are non-trivial atomic measures that have the "version 1" property. For example, take the Lebesgue measure restricted to the set of all subsets of $[0, 1]$ whose measure is $0$ or $1$. (The key point is that the question does not require that $\mu(F) < \mu(E)$). But anyway, I think version 2 was the intention.

@IzaakvanDongen I don't think you need to delete your answer. You seem to have written it while I was editing my answer.

I didn't write any answers to this question! I guess you have confused me with someone else. I thought your answer was good, anyway - my comment is just a small nitpick.

@IzaakvanDongen I am sorry, I have indeed confused you with somebody else. I do really like your counterexample to your claim for this correspond to non-atomic measures.
